# How do I get my buttons to work in the fragment?

Tags: android, button, android-fragments

I am still having a problem with just adding a button to the screen and getting it to execute my code.  Right now, I will be happy with select the button and getting the "log,d (msg);" to work.  The problem may be due to all my code in the fragment and/or combination of buttons and a list that I scroll on the same screen.   It is probably a very basic problem.

My application first starts with a scrolling list created by a cursor from SQLite table.  So it is an open ended list.  Select an item and I get a detail screen to allow add, update or delete.  That all works.

Now I am adding 3 buttons above the list.

I am a newbie, and the book I started with said to create a fragment, so the screen with the list is coded that way.  (The detail screen is rewritten to just the activity.)

I have tried lots of things, but roughly three ways below:

In my onCreate method:

```
"btn_Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()"
```

As suggested in a recent - reply - This executes fragment onCreate , then crashes with these messages:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.dummies.android.taskreminder/com.dummies.android.
taskreminder. EventListActivity}:Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class fragment
```

As a separate method after the onCreate:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

This causes a loop - repeating the onCreate several times then crashes with this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.dummies.android.taskreminder/com.dummies.android.
taskreminder.EventListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

3 I added this to the XML file in button definition:

android:onClick="MyButton"

and

```
public void MyButton(View v)
    {
     Log.d(". . . " + v);
    }
```

This allowed the application to load, but when I selected the button, it crashed when I selected the button with the following message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method MyButton(View) in the activity
```

This is pieces from the fragment: eventListFragment.java

```
public class EventListFragment extends ListFragment
                                  implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
  {
   . . . .
    List strRecord = new ArrayList(3);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        . . . .
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
       )
//------------------------------------
// THIS IS EXAMPLE # 1
//     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
//     ComponentInfo{com.dummies.android.taskreminder/com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListActivity}:
//     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class fragment

    btn_Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        // you may want to perform your clicks here.
        Log.d("EventLst","S create view btnAddEvent:" + v);
        }
    });   
//-------------------------------------


  }   //----> END: public void onCreate  

//-------------------------------------
//     THIS IS EXAMPLE #2:
//  it give me this error on initial load:
//  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
//  ComponentInfo{com.dummies.android.taskreminder/com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListActivity}:
//  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_list, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Add);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
           {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
               {
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (activity != null)
                   {
                    Log.d("EventLst","S create view btnAddEvent:" + v);
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "GOT button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               }
             }   );
        return view;
       }
//---------------------------------------


    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor)
       {
        . . . 
         while  (cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
            {
             strRecord.add(iRecNo, strDate + ": "  + strC[2]);
            }
         lstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                  R.layout.event_row, R.id.text1, strRecord);
          setListAdapter(lstAdapter);
```

This is the main layout: event_list.XML
Note: android:onClick="MyButton" only in try #3 above

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:name="com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListFragment" >

 <Button  android:id="@+id/btn_Add"
    android:onClick="MyButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"   
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:text="@string/add" />

  <Button  android:id="@+id/btn_Exit"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Add" 
    android:text="@string/exit" />

  <Button  android:id="@+id/btn_Other"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_Exit" 
    android:text="@string/other" />

 <fragment
    android:name="com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Add"  />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the row to create the scrow list: event_row.XML

```
  <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:padding="2dip" />
```

Luksprog requested this information in his reply please post or at least make available to him/her.

First I created this XML file, event_list_activity.xml, guessed a little on the filename:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Also added to strings:

```
<string name="container">EventContainer</string>
```

Ran my test and this is the complete log: (First three records from my code):

```
04-28 16:09:24.504: D/EventLst(258): X onCrt: x01strI:eventname
04-28 16:09:24.544: D/EventLst(258): X onCrt: x02 START
04-28 16:09:24.584: D/EventLst(258): X onCrt: x03 START
04-28 16:09:24.624: D/AndroidRuntime(258): Shutting down VM
04-28 16:09:24.646: W/dalvikvm(258): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b1d8)
04-28 16:09:24.646: E/AndroidRuntime(258): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-28 16:09:24.646: W/dalvikvm(258): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b1d8)
04-28 16:09:24.646: E/AndroidRuntime(258): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
         ComponentInfo{com.dummies.android.taskreminder/com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListActivity}:
         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class fragment
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33:
         Error inflating class fragment
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:582)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         com.android.internal.policy.impl.WimmWindow.setContentView(WimmWindow.java:181)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListActivity.onCreate(EventListActivity.java:22)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  ... 11 more
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListFragment.onCreate(EventListFragment.java:98)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1437)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:877)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1066)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1168)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:280)
04-28 16:09:25.065: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at
         android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
```

Next I added your statements below and get errors below is from the start of the fragment to the end of on create Note: I also had to add: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

```
package com.dummies.android.taskreminder;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;  
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
//* below insures that you are using the ...v4 for version android 1.6
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment; 
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks; 
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

public class EventListFragment extends ListFragment
                                  implements 
                                  LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
  {
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    List strRecId = new ArrayList();

    private ListAdapter lstAdapter;
    private Button btn_Add;
    private Button myButton;

    List strRecord = new ArrayList(3);
    List strFields = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//---------------------------------------------------------------        
     // assuming you use FragmentActivity
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.container, new EvetListFragment());
        ft.commit();        

// errors above:   
// For: getSupportFragmentManager()
//  "The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type EventListFragment" 
// For: EvetListFragment());
//   "EvetListFragment cannot be resolved to a type"
//----------------------------------------------------------------

//  BELOW READS FROM DATABASE AND DISPLAYS EVENTNAME
//  THEN ALLOWS UPDATE OF THEM ABD INSERT FROM EXISTING        
//        Log.d("EventLst","X onCrt: x01 START" ); 

        String[]  strItems =  new String[]  
           { 
            EventProvider.COLUMN_EVENTNAME
           };
        Log.d("EventLst","X onCrt: x01strI:" + strItems[0]);          
        int[] iCnt = new int[]
            {  
             R.id.text1
            };

        mAdapter =  new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.event_row,
                    null, strItems, iCnt,  0);
        Log.d("EventLst","X onCrt: x02 START" );

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        Log.d("EventLst","X onCrt: x03 START" );
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// I thought this set my OnClickListener.  Without this code, the application runs 
//   but the buttons don't do anything  
        btn_Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {
      @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
             {
              Log.d("EventLst","S onclkBtn2" + v);
             }
         }  );
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      }   //----> END: public void onCreate
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code a lot of problems:

Please post the full stacktrace, that `InflateException` tells you the reason why the fragment can't be inflated. The most likely reason is that you extend a `ListFragment` and override `onCreateView()` to inflate your own layout which doesn't contain a `ListView` with the id `android.R.id.list`(`@android:id/list` in the xml file). Even if that exception isn't thrown your code would still fail because you'll get yourself in a stackoverflow error, your fragment's layout is a layout file which contains the same fragment(which will be loaded again and so on...).

Remove:

```
android:name="com.dummies.android.taskreminder.EventListFragment"
```

from the layout. The layout should be like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

 <Button  android:id="@+id/btn_Add"    
    android:layout_width="50dp" <!-- you should avoid fixed sizes -->
    android:layout_height="30dp"   
    android:textSize="12sp" <!-- use sp units for text size! -->
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:text="@string/add" />

  <Button  android:id="@+id/btn_Exit"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_Add" 
    android:text="@string/exit" />

  <Button  android:id="@+id/btn_Other"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn_Exit" 
    android:text="@string/other" />

 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_Add"  />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This would be the layout for the fragment. The layout for the `Activity` would be :

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

To add the fragment(in the `onCreate()` method):

```
// assuming you use FragmentActivity
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.container, new EvetListFragment());
ft.commit();
```

You could then replace the `EventListFragment` by using `R.id.container`.

In your `EventListFragment` set the `OnClickListener` on your buttons and also your adapter in the `onActivityCreated()` callback. The `onClick` attribute will look for that method at the `Activity` level so just set the `OnClickListener` manually.

Comment: Appreciate the answer.
I will post more, but I went to google site that said to go to properties / java compiler and change compliance from 1.6.  Result:

 "Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. …."

W/ properties grayed, can't go back, nothing runs…Fortunately have recent back-up & won't take long to get back to where I was.

However, you may have already helped.  I don't have an activity.xml just the event_row & event_List . Since the list, select from the list worked, just the buttons failed, I thought I had what I need.  So I will also try that.

Comment: PS:
I am newbie to android, - my first app, so no surprise my code is bad.  I notice a monitor from Charlotte, maybe I can buy a tutoring session.

It is for my WIMMOne watch, so orientation chg, positions fixed & one app covers entire little screen.  That is why I had specific positions.

Again, thanks, will implement what you have and post more of the log if you haven't already solved it.
Clark

Comment: I posted the log you requested and other results last night, apparently they haven't put it up on the site.  Since the log is more than what will fit in a comment, I edited and posted the new information to the end.  I appreciate your reply, and would expect them to make it available soon.

Thanks, Clark

Comment: @ClarkG If you want to add extra details edit your question and add them. You don't understand how fragments work. In the `Activity` you'll only add the `EventListFragment`(the code I posted). Searching for the views and setting listeners on them will be done in the `EventListFragment`(as those views are in the fragment layout and not the activity), in the `onCreateView()` or `onActivityCreated()` callbacks.

Comment: First I very much appreciate your help and patience! - 

I did edit my question to add additional information, it said "only viewable to me until reviewed by a peer".  Apparently that reviewer didn't like it, so I just tried it again and asked to at least let you see it.

If you need more, let me know, there is nothing I consider proprietary, so would have no problem posting or sharing the entire project.

Comment: @ClarkG From your edit it seems you didn't understand what I said in my answer. If you can post your project somewhere(or if you have a link to a repository(git)) it would be easier for me to make the appropriate corrections to your code(along with some explanations).

Comment: That would be really great!!  I would appreciate any help I can get.

Can I sign up for repository(git), or is there a temp place in stackoverflow I can place it in? 

Not opposed to emailing it somewhere.

Thanks,
Clark

Comment: You should have it, if not let me know. - Clark

Comment: WOW!

Just a few changes - well, OK, basically a re-write!

A fun aside: I knew the exit was bad, but an emergency fix; I got the "pre-buttons" version working in the emulator and excitedly side loaded it to my real watch, and executed it.  I realized I could not exit and had to reboot the watch just to get back to see the time!  So the fastest fix was use list entry 1 as a "button" and "android.os.Process.killProcess…" as a temp solution.

In any case, I am reviewing your comments and will learn a bunch from it.

Very many thanks,
Clark

Comment: Very many thanks to Luksprog for helping me and answering my question.  Can I mark the answer even though the actual code isn't posted, or should I edit my question with the corrected code and remove my junk unneeded stuff?

Comment: Answered based on great help from Luksprog.